# gapi.auth.authorize() not calling its callback method

Tags: javascript, android, google-calendar-api, google-authentication

I am trying to implement Google Calendar usin "Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript". Its code is provided here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/source/browse/samples/authSample.html

However, the method `gapi.auth.authorize` is never calling its callback method `handleAuthResult`.

Please take a note that I have generated client id and api key for Android. Scope provided in my code is **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar**

Please let me know how to overcome this problem.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Any errors in LogCat?